Is it better to store multiple image sizes in drawable directories or just a single large image in assets for Android apps?
I'm developing a native Android app and am considering the best way to manage image resources. Traditionally, we've been advised to store multiple sizes of each image in various drawable folders (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, and drawable-xxxhdpi) to match different device screen densities. However, I'm questioning whether this approach is still relevant or necessary today.
Given advancements in Android's handling of images and screen densities, is it more efficient or advantageous to store just a single, high-resolution image (e.g., a 400x400 image for an originally 100x100 image) in the assets folder and resize it dynamically in the app based on the device's screen density?
For example, for an image initially meant to be 100x100:
Traditionally, I would store these variants:
drawable-mdpi = 100x100
drawable-hdpi = 150x150
drawable-xhdpi = 200x200
drawable-xxhdpi = 300x300
drawable-xxxhdpi = 400x400

However, on a device like the Google Pixel 7 with a screen density factor of 2.625, the system retrieves the 300x300 image from drawable-xxhdpi and then resizes it to 263x263px. This results in the image being resized twice, potentially degrading its quality.
I've noticed that many apps seem to store their images mainly in the assets folder rather than in the drawable directories. Can anyone confirm if this is a common practice? What is the recommended approach in 2024 for handling images in Android apps to balance between image quality and app performance?

IMHO this is mostly a performance question.
Quality should not be an issue since the pre-processing (downsampling to density buckets) is done on the desktop where you can use high quality methods (e.g. Lanczos filtering)
It's clear that resizing once at compile time is better than resizing many times at runtime. But what about fractional density factors? Well, resizing from 300x300 to 240x240 at runtime is still cheaper than resizing from 400x400.
Another benefit of using drawable resources is that they are pre-processed by the AAPT2 tool, which analyses them and in some cases can reduce the size.
You are right that modern devices are more powerful and the performance difference is less noticeable. But some projects are more demanding than others. So there is no boolean answer to your question.
EDIT: We can also consider the ethical side of the question. Should we care about squeezing that extra performance even when it's not necessary? Should we care about draining the phone battery more than needed? Should we care about environmental impact of inefficient software running on the global scale?
